# How to remove a command added to the Toolbar using addCommandToRightBar(Command)?

Tags: codenameone

after having added a command to the Toolbar using addCommandToRightBar(Command), I want to remove or hide the command again (e.g. when I select/unselect on a specific tab in Tabs). In the SideMenuBar there is removeCommand(Command) for this, but I can't figure out how to do the same for Toolbar. Any suggestions how I can achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[removeCommand](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Form.html#removeCommand-com.codename1.ui.Command-) works but you should remember to `revalidate()`:

```
Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);
Form hi = new Form("Bar");
Command cmd = hi.getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar("Bla", null, (e) -> Log.p("Bla"));
hi.getToolbar().addCommandToLeftBar("Remove", null, (e) -> {
    hi.removeCommand(cmd);
    hi.revalidate();
});

hi.show();
```

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate your answer! I will try that. However, it seems a bit contra-intuitive (and not documented?) that you use addCommand on the Toolbar  to add a command, but when you remove it you must do it from the Form. But maybe it's logical when knowing the inner workings of the Forms.

Comment: That's a good point. Originally only the form's `addCommand()` existed so remove command there made sense.