# How to remove commands added to overflow menu

Tags: codenameone

When I add commands to the Toolbar using `toolbar.addCommandToOverflowMenu(cmd)`and then try to remove them using the form's `removeCommand`(as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293862/how-to-remove-a-command-added-to-the-toolbar-using-addcommandtorightbarcommand)) it doesn't work. What is the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be missing. We'll add a `Toolbar.removeOverflowCommand(Command)` method to the next update.

Comment: Only gotten around to updating my CN1 local sources now and it isn't working. The `removeOverflowCommand` is added to `ToolbarSideMenu` which is used internally in `Toolbar` for the private variable `sidemenu`. And sidemenu can only be accessed via `getSidemenu()` which returns a `MenuBar`, effectively preventing access to the command. And `ToolbarSideMenu` is not public, so I can't even force a typecast on the result of `getSidemenu()`. Can you fix this?

Comment: Overflow and sidemenu are different things. RemoveOverflowCommand was designed to work with the overflow menu only. Remove command should work with side menu

Comment: My point was that the `removeOverflowCommand()` is not accessible.

Comment: You can try `getToolbar().removeOverflowCommand()` to see that it doesn't work. Hope you can fix it.

Comment: Ugh, sorry about that. This should be fixed next Friday, just tested it.